# How Do I Find Who Last Edited a Record or Table in a Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I believe that I have most of the work done for whoever wants to tackle this question.

I have the following query built:

```
USE MyDataBase;
GO

SELECT DB_NAME(ius.[database_id]) AS [Database],
       OBJECT_NAME(ius.[object_id]) AS [TableName],
       MAX(ius.[last_user_lookup]) AS [last_user_lookup],
       MAX(ius.[last_user_scan]) AS [last_user_scan],
       MAX(ius.[last_user_seek]) AS [last_user_seek]
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS ius

WHERE ius.[database_id] = DB_ID()

GROUP BY ius.[database_id], ius.[object_id];
```

If possible, how do I add which user it was that made a change?

Comment: "I believe that I have most of the work done for whoever wants to tackle this question." -- Oh boy, that's a million miles from right.

Comment: First question would be "made a change to what?"

Comment: If the question is "Who changed a row in a table in a database?" the answer is... unless you've setup auditing before they made the change there is no way of getting that information. If it's a different question, please update your question with more information.

Comment: Which native tools can I employ in SQL Server to give me this information from now on?

Comment: You can set up SQL Auditing, CDC, create audit columns etc.  I've got a run through on a number of your options here: https://www.sqlshack.com/intro-auditing-sql-server/ You will have to set something up though before you'll get any real information. It isn't natively collected.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this if you do not have a historical or archive table that store this data. You have to create an AuditDb and create some DML trigger.

**OR**

You have to use a third-party log reader (if log is not shrinked) like [ApexSQL LOG](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)